# No route exception - Java, memcached

Tags: java, memcached

Few days ago i found exception in catalina log file:

> I/O error: No route to host; nested exception is
>   java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host

it's connection to memcached.

Do you have any ideas, that can it be, and how to avoid it?

I was looking for solution, but i have no idea, what happened.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/NoRouteToHostException.html):

> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to a remote address and port. Typically, the remote host cannot be reached because of an intervening firewall, or if an intermediate router is down.

Something was blocking the connection.

1. maybe your DNS was not working,
2. maybe there were some troubles with firewall
3. maybe a problem with the network interface. This could happen if the network cable was unplugged.